# How to delete Rows in Parse

Tags: ios, database, swift, parse-platform

Currently I have an app that queries an array of businesses from Yelp Search API and it puts it into my Parse Database.

Here is the code for that:

```
let businessToParse = PFObject(className: "Business")
businessToParse["name"] = yelpBusinessMock.name
businessToParse["address"] = yelpBusinessMock.address
businessToParse["categories"] = yelpBusinessMock.categories
businessToParse["distance"] = yelpBusinessMock.distance
businessToParse["imageURLString"] = yelpBusinessMock.imageURLString
businessToParse.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (sucessful: Bool, errors: NSError?) -> Void in
    if(sucessful) {

    } else {
        print(errors?.description)
    }
})
```

However, the problem is that when I query with a different query string, the other data stays in the database, which is not what I want.

What I want to do is basically replace the current data that is already in the Parse Database with the new Data. Is there anyway I could do this? I tried `businessToParse.deleteInBackground()`, but that seem to do anything...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects : [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            for object in objects! {
                object.deleteInBackground()
            }
        }
    })
```